# Why is discordjs not using the message object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to send a series of buttons before collection, but the collector doesn't work when it runs, passing an error of

> const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType:  ComponentType.Button, time: 15000 });
> TypeError: message.createMessageComponentCollector is not a function

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelIDD);
        message = channel.send({ content: 'I think you should,', ephemeral: true, embeds: [embed], components: [row] })

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return true;
        };
        const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.Button, time: 15000 });
        collector.on('collect', i => {
            i.reply(`${i.user.id} clicked on the ${i.customId} button.`);
        });
        
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} interactions.`);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `message` is not a `Message`. `channel.send` returns a Promise. If you want to get the `Message` object, you'll need to resolve it first.

```js
const message = await channel.send({
  content: 'I think you should,',
  ephemeral: true,
  embeds: [embed],
  components: [row],
})
```

Then you can create your collector:

```js
const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({
  componentType: ComponentType.Button,
  time: 15000,
});
```

Comment: Still got an error

(    const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({
                                          ^

TypeError: message.createMessageComponentCollector is not a function   )

Had to get rid of the await is the only change I made, since its not in an async.

Comment: So I told you to use `await` because you would need that to resolve the promise and you removed that one thing and wonder why there was still an error. As you mentioned it was not in an async function so you'll need to make it an async function. Add the [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keyword.

Comment: I did so too, didn't work regardless.

Comment: I don't think you added the `async` keyword to the correct place then. Feel free to upload your code to a site like pastebin.com, post the link here and I can take a look at it ;)

Comment: So sorry! I had the async in the right place, it worked once I redeployed my commands and used your method! Thanks!